# Flash memory and set to read only , Is it virus?

Tags: disk, readonly, flash-memory, hdparm

Becuase some of limitation of MS.Windows, my friends and my family gime their flash memory to solve their problem. Such as format, partitioning in Linux with the  `cfidsk ,parted, sfidsk(dump and manipualting partition table),mkfs.*, dd` commands,  and other operations. 
But i get the new problem with set of flash memory, yes, bit of read only set to 1:

When use :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# hdparm -r /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 readonly      =  1 (off)
```

When i use:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

And use :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# hdparm -r /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 readonly      =  0 (off)
```

But when i unplug and plug flash i prevent with the previous result:

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# hdparm -r /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
 readonly      =  1 (off)
```

When i use `cfdisk /dev/sdb` or any command i get read-only disk error,

This is 4th disk i get same error.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You *are* unmounting the flash drive when removing it, correct?

Comment: Sure, I remember all of them behave such as same......

Comment: Does log files reveal anything atypical? Logs as in e.g. `dmesg` or the like.

Comment: I only want to find who has experience in this aspect or not, i cheched all of log file even dmesg (kernel ring buffer)